# Est-ce d’usage de dire à l’oral « juste pour être certain/sûr, il s’agit bien de.... »?

Tags: choix-de-mot, constructions, formulation-idiomatique, formulation

Juste pour être certain, il s’agit bien du traitement des cicatrices au laser et non pas celui qui nécessite un acte chirurgical?

J’avais aussi en tête « Pour clarifier ...» voire « Pour clarifier l’information qui a été dite, il s’agit bien de... »

Quelle serait selon vous la tournure la plus en usage? N’hésitez pas à me faire connaître d’autres constructions plus élégantes, mais gardez à l’esprit que je cherche avant tout une tournure qui se dit à l’oral. Merci.

Comment: "Si j'ai bien compris, ..." est très courant, et ne met pas en cause la façon dont ça a été expliqué. "Pour clairifer" sous-entend que quelque chose n'est pas clair dans l'explication. A l'oral, on peut aussi commencer par "Donc", comme dans "Donc... il s'agit bien du traitement, ..." Mais l'intonation joue un role, un marque comme une courte pause après le "donc". Cette formulation ne serait pas nécessairement bien comprise par écrit, mais est courante à l'oral.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Juste pour être sûr*** est très courant, on peut y ajouter ***que je ne trompe pas*** ou ***que j'ai bien compris***.

D'autres formules du même style :

***Juste pour que je sois sûr de ne pas me tromper*** ou ***d'avoir bien compris***.

***On est bien d'accord,**…*

***Vous me confirmez que**…*